# Do we need to signup for an unlimited plan to be able to test the shipping / carrier api? shopify api

Tags: shopify

Do we need to signup for an unlimited plan to be able to test the shipping / carrier api? shopify api

I've faced the problem which we must take sign up for premium.
Does anyone able to test shipping rates and other without purchasing premium

Answer (score 0):

Setup a development shop as a partner, for free. Those shops come with the ability to setup and test things like that. You do not need an actual paid Shopify store to test and develop your Apps. Use a development shop instead.